FIlament PHP | FileUpload Issue | Waiting for size | GCP
I need your help with FileUpload using GCP. I have two ways of uploading images:

Using RichEditor: This one works perfectly. Basically, when I upload the image, I can see them without any issues.
Using FileUpload: This is where I encounter the issue. I was able to upload it and I can open the file; however, the preview keeps on loading and telling me "waiting for size" forever.

Here's my resource code:
Forms\Components\FileUpload::make('attachments')
                                    ->columnSpan(2)
                                    ->fetchFileInformation(false)
                                    ->label('Attachments')
                                    ->multiple()
                                    ->previewable()
                                    ->reorderable()
                                    ->downloadable()
                                    ->openable()
                                    ->directory('attachments')
                                    ->storeFileNamesIn('original_filenames')
                                    ->disabled($user
                                        ->cannot('admin:customer_support_request:view_attachments'))
                                    ->hidden($user
                                        ->cannot('admin:customer_support_request:edit_attachments')),

Here's my filesystem.php file code:
'gcs-media' => [
            'driver' => 'gcs',
            'project_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID', 'project_id'),
            'bucket' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_MEDIA_STORAGE_BUCKET', 'test.com'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'bucket_url' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_MEDIA_BUCKET_URL'),
            'storage_api_uri' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_MEDIA_BUCKET_URL'),
            'visibility_handler' => \League\Flysystem\GoogleCloudStorage\UniformBucketLevelAccessVisibility::class,
            'key_file' => [
                'type' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_MEDIA_ACCOUNT_TYPE'),
                'private_key_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_MEDIA_PRIVATE_KEY_ID'),
                'private_key' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_MEDIA_PRIVATE_KEY'),
                'client_email' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_MEDIA_CLIENT_EMAIL'),
                'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_MEDIA_CLIENT_ID'),
                'auth_uri' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_MEDIA_AUTH_URI'),
                'token_uri' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_MEDIA_TOKEN_URI'),
                'auth_provider_x509_cert_url' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_MEDIA_AUTH_PROVIDER_CERT_URL'),
                'client_x509_cert_url' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_MEDIA_CLIENT_CERT_URL'),
            ],
            'throw' => true,
        ],

I have already updated my .env file the APP_URL there and seems to be correct because I was able to upload the file in my GCP and I can see the images when using RichEditor. I have also tried updating the php.ini file to: variables_order = GPCS but nothing works. I have already added this: ->fetchFileInformation(false) and it is still the same. Can anyone assist me with this. Thank you.

This has been fixed on the server side. CORS is not enabled. All you need to do is allow access from the source.

Check image path or source path
